# How to check for BOM in postgres text columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, byte-order-mark

We have some encoding issues and I need to check whether a BOM is already present in a PostgreSQL text column. I used

```
select convert(varbinary, columnXY) from tableXY where id = 1;
```

for MS SQL successfully, but don't find equivalent conversions for PostgreSQL. I found this [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) and tried with `decode(columnXY, 'hex')`, but that is not working.

Comment: Postgres has a `convert()` function as well, but I'm not sure if it can handle UTF with a BOM.

Comment: There is no "varbinary" datatype in postGres, so i think you need to look at this link - [bytea doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)

Comment: @KrishnrajRana I found `select decode(replace(columnXY, '\\', '\\\\'), 'escape') from tableXY where id = 1;`, the result is `\357\273\277<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Which unicode chars are that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider the binary representation of the `TEXT` column by converting it to `BYTEA` (edit: not by a direct cast, better use `convert_to(text,'UTF-8')` instead) and searching the BOM sequence in it as a series of bytes.

as an SQL expression:

```
position('\xefbbbf'::bytea IN convert_to(your_text_column,'UTF-8'))=1
```

`0` as the result of `position(...)` would mean the BOM is not in the string.
`1` means it's at the beginning of the string.

Comment: That is working. Now I also know that the result of `select decode(replace(your_text_column, '\\', '\\\\'), 'escape') from tableXY where id = 1;`, which is `\357\273\277` must be `\xefbbbf`. But how is this?

Comment: `\357\273\277` is the octal equivalent of the hexadecimal `\xefbbbf`

Comment: I got that, but how to convert it from octal to bytea (which I can read).

Comment: I wouldn't bother with octal for this but `'\357\273\277'::bytea` is the closest answer I can think of.

Comment: I don't bother with octal for this, but for other possible BOMs. `select '\357\273\277'::bytea` has the result `\357\273\277`. As already stated by you, this is octal bytea. What is needed is the hex bytea representation...

Comment: That's the pgadmin default value for bytea. It can be changed with:

`update pg_settings set setting = 'hex' WHERE name = 'bytea_output';`

Comment: @jan You can `encode('\357\273\277'::bytea, 'HEX')`

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: Nearly done, now how to do this in one step? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342291/how-to-convert-postgresql-escape-bytea-to-hex-bytea