# How to convert PostgreSQL escape bytea to hex bytea?

Tags: postgresql, byte-order-mark

I got the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23340643/1184842) to check for one certain BOM in a PostgreSQL text column. What I really like to do would be to have something more general, i.e. something like

```
select decode(replace(textColumn, '\\', '\\\\'), 'escape') from tableXY;
```

The result of a UTF8 BOM is:

```
\357\273\277
```

Which is octal bytea and can be converted by switching the output of bytea in pgadmin:

```
update pg_settings set setting = 'hex' WHERE name = 'bytea_output';
select '\357\273\277'::bytea
```

The result is:

```
\xefbbbf
```

What I would like to have is this result as one query, e.g.

```
update pg_settings set setting = 'hex' WHERE name = 'bytea_output';
select decode(replace(textColumn, '\\', '\\\\'), 'escape') from tableXY;
```

But that doesn't work. The result is empty, probably because the decode cannot handle hex output.

Comment: It is possible to convert by `encode('\357\273\277'::bytea, 'hex')`, but I don't get it to working in combination with the other query, i.e. `select encode(decode(replace(textColumn, '\\', '\\\\'), 'escape')::bytea, 'hex') from tableXY;` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you set the context by telling your PG version and more to the point, the result of `show standard_conforming_strings;` ?

Comment: Also, do you expect this `decode(..., 'escape')` to be applied to any kind of string or strings that match a specific syntax? (in the former case I believe you're on the wrong track to start with)

Comment: @DanielVérité: I use pgAdmin III 1.16.1, the standard_conforming_strings is on, I need a query for arbitrary text columns. In the moment this is always the special case of XML data that sometimes starts with a UTF8 BOM. I found out that in at least one case that query also returns no result. In that row a UTF8 BOM is present, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the final purpose is to get the hexadecimal representation of all the bytes that constitute the strings in `textColumn`, this can be done with:

```
SELECT encode(convert_to(textColumn, 'UTF-8'), 'hex') from tableXY;
```

It does not depend on `bytea_output`. BTW, this setting plays a role only at the final stage of a query, when a result column is of type `bytea` and has to be returned in text format to the client (which is the most common case, and what pgAdmin does). It's a matter of representation, the actual **values** represented (the series of bytes) are identical.

In the query above, the result is of type `text`, so this is irrelevant anyway.

I think that your query with `decode(..., 'escape')`  can't work because the argument is supposed to be encoded in `escape` format and it's not, per comments it's normal xml strings.

Comment: Like I saw with the `decode(..., 'escape')` query, this query is not working always. In two of 14 cases it works and looks exactly like what I want. But in 12 of 14 cases the result of the query is empty. It is not related to the BOM, as two rows with BOM have empty results, the 2 results of no BOM and 10 other lines without BOM have no result too. If I remove the encode part, already the inner convert_to has only 4 results, i.e. 8 results are lost by the convert_to and 2 results by the encode.

Comment: Ain't `SELECT encode(uuio_configuration_c::bytea, 'hex') from uic_UIObjectConfiguration;` better as your query? It has the same result, i.e. only 2 of 14 rows are not empty.

Comment: I cannot, because the entries are too long for comments. I think that is the problem too, because the two working entries are the shortest (under 1000 chars). All entries not working have more then 2800 chars. I'm only interested in the beginning of the entries, can the query only convert the first 100 chars?

Comment: substr(longtext,1,100)

Answer (score 1):

With the great help of Daniel-Vérité I use this general query now to check for all kind of BOM or unicode char problems:

```
select encode(textColumn::bytea, 'hex'), * from tableXY;
```

I had problem with pgAdmin and too long columns, as they had no result. I used that query for pgAdmin:

```
select encode(substr(textColumn,1,100)::bytea, 'hex'), * from tableXY;
```

Thanks Daniel!

Comment: Note that the empty results are almost certainly a display problem with pgAdmin. The SQL functions involved here are not known to have a problem with large texts.

Comment: @DanielVérité: You are right, other clients have no problem with `select encode(textColumn::bytea, 'hex'), * from tableXY;`